# How to set up Eclipse to run with as much RAM as possible?

Tags: eclipse, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a maximum number you can set Xmx to when trying to increase jvm memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461260/is-there-a-maximum-number-you-can-set-xmx-to-when-trying-to-increase-jvm-memory)

On my x64 Windows with 8GB physical RAM I'd like to increase performance of my Flash Builder (an IDE built on top of Eclipse). This is usually done by adding something like this to eclipse.ini:

```
-Xmx1024m
```

I'd like to use something like 4096 as my machine has enough RAM but when I do so, the Eclipse won't start with this error message:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=-1
```

Do I need to set up some other startup options? Is Eclipse capable of running with that much memory?

Comment: Sorry, this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461260/is-there-a-maximum-number-you-can-set-xmx-to-when-trying-to-increase-jvm-memory . Can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the 32bit Sun (Oracle) JVM? If so, then you cannot set xmx above 2GB.