# Why again and again my Flash builder shutdown/close during development after coming this alert?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

The Flash Builder restart after showing this alert.

```
Unhandled event loop exception 
unable to create new native thread
```

Note That i am using Flash Builder 4.6

Thanks

Comment: You're in the wrong place with this. Contact Adobe support.

Comment: check this out... http://www.redcodelabs.com/2012/03/eclipse-speed-up-flashbuilder/ Out of memory may be your issue

Comment: @weltraumpirat how to downvote a comment?

Comment: @NoobASThreeDeveloper FB is a commercial product, which clearly has some issues - the first place to ask after a crash like that is the vendor's support. No need to troll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a big project with lot of files and libraries?

In my experience, this is caused by low Java memory.

**Option A:** Solution is to increase memory for Flash Builder.

Adobe says: [Improving Compiler Performance for Large Projects](http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/2010/02/improving_compiler_performance.html)

Edit FlashBuilder.ini lines with Xms and Xmx

```
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:PermSize=64m
```

*My computer with 8 GB RAM allows max increase for 1g, not more. We have project so big that we were forced to migrate to IntelliJ IDEA with external compiler*

Link: [Maximum for Java VM is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461260/is-there-a-maximum-number-you-can-set-xmx-to-when-trying-to-increase-jvm-memory)

**Option B:** Create new Flash Builder/eclipse workspace and recreate your project. (Or remove `.metadata` folder from your workspace).

Maybe there are some local changes that corrupted something inside the Flash Builder.

*Can you reproduce the same error on another PC?*

**Option C:** Leave Flash Builder and migrate to other software. I suggest IntelliJ IDEA which uses external compiler and that way the compilation process can use more memory (Flash Builder shares its memory with the compiler).

Comment: i already edit FlashBuilder.ini -Xms512m
-Xmx1024m but same result.

Comment: @TahirAlvi as I said, we had the project so big, that were not able to work in FB4.6 anymore. Is your project big also? For example we have 38 external SWC libs and 3500+ files. This compiles (mxmlc compiler) in 16 secs on i7-2600K CPU with SSD disk. Compilation of the same project in FB4.6 took nearly 2 min on the same PC.

Comment: Thanks man, Now you understand all the situation clearly. My project contain external 13 Library project and 3664 files.