# In Java, how do I find out what is my maximum heap size?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have the following class in Java :

```
public class MemoryUsage 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vector v = new Vector();
        while (true)
        {
            byte b[] = new byte[1048576];

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie){}        
            v.add(b);
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            System.out.println( "free memory: " + rt.freeMemory() );
        }
    }

    public void showCurrentTime() 
    {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(time);   
    } 
}
```

And I want to limit how much memory can be used by this program. I tried to set an initial and maximum size (from command-line), like follows :

```
C:\JMX_code\Memory_test>java -Xms2m -Xmx4068M MemoryUsage
Error occurred during initialization of VM
The size of the object heap + VM data exceeds the maximum representable size
```

But this doesn't work. How do I figure out what is my own maximum heap size ?

My Java version info. is as follows :

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13) Java HotSpot(TM)
>   64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: How much RAM is on your machine and which version of Java are you running?

Comment: @Coffee what is your RAM + swap memory size? I doubt if it is less than 4gb. Can you try with -Xmx =2048m.

Comment: Which version of Java are you running (including whether it is 32 or 64 bit) and what platform are you running on?

Comment: @Ishmael - I have 8 GB of RAM

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461260/is-there-a-maximum-number-you-can-set-xmx-to-when-trying-to-increase-jvm-memory) might be related.

Comment: You may need to specify `-d64` on the command line to force the JVM to accept the specified heap size. [This site](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/invalid-initial-and-maximum-heap-size.html) explains some of these heap problems.

Comment: @callyalater - not sure why, but this works fine on my Mac, ... just not on Windows

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu - not sure why, but this works fine on my Mac, ... just not on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to:

```
-Xms2034M -Xmx4068M MemoryUsage
```